# Rails + Filepicker gem: how to allow to upload only images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mime-types, filepicker

I am using the official Filepicker gem for Rails applications and so far, if I want to specify the mimetypes as all images, I am doing it this way:

```
extensions: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif"
```

On the official documentation page on the Filepicker website, there is shown this approach:

```
image/*
```

So I've tried to use this approach for the Filepicker gem in the used notation:

```
extensions: "image/*"
```

But when I try to upload something, it gives error regarding to an incorrect file type... How to properly allow all kind of images?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing `extensions` and `mimetypes`. From the [readme](https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails):

- extensions - The extensions of file types you want to support for this upload. Ex: ".png,.jpg".
- mimetypes - The file types you want to support for this upload. Ex: "image/png,text/*".

Offtopic: Why is this the *official* Filepicker gem?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice it. Inattention. "Offtopic: Why is this the official Filepicker gem?" -> Beucase it's from the creators of Filepicker.

Comment: Ah ok, I missed that Filepicker is a real service and not just some file upload *assistant*. For the real problem: Did you try `mimetypes: "image/*"`?